# CSS to have image floating on right of description list item

Tags: html, image, css

I have a description list like this:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Employer 2</dt>
  <dd>2013 - present</dd>
  <dd>Job description</dd>

  <dt>Employer 1</dt>
  <dd>2010 - 2013</dd>
  <dd>Other job description</dd>
</dl>
```

I would like to have an image floating on the right of the page with the logo of employer 1 and 2. The top of each image would be at the level of the "Employer 1" and "Employer 2" lines.

Is there any way to do this easily with CSS?

Thanks a lot in advance!

-- Arthur;

Comment: Have you done something so far? if you share your CSS I can definitely help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to change the HTML and split it into two lists that are wrapped by two DIVs like this:

```css
.wrap1>img {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.wrap1 {
  clear: both;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/70x100/d7a">
  <dl>
    <dt>Employer 2</dt>
    <dd>2013 - present</dd>
    <dd>Job description</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
<div class="wrap1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/70x100/7da">
  <dl>
    <dt>Employer 1</dt>
    <dd>2010 - 2013</dd>
    <dd>Other job description</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```